# C# Sort a list from the values of another list

Tags: c#, list, sorting

hoping you can help me with this.

Okay I have two lists.

List1 - Gets the names of files without a path (so I can list the names on dynamically created buttons). More so for visual purposes only.

List2 - Stores the actual path to the file.

Now I have done List1.Sort(); and List2.Sort().
But being they are alphabetical, A direct path from C:/// is different than Hello.png. <(Just an example name)>

So the problem I am facing is, List1 and 2 aren't identical in where the actual elements are stored. (Which does make sense).

So is there a way to like sort List2 to match the same order as List1? Or vice versa.. So when I click the button, it loads the proper image,etc that it needs to.

Comment: Why have two lists in the first place? If they each refer to the "same thing" (file on disk, only difference is full vs. filename), then I would put them into a single data structure, possibly `List<Tuple<string, string>>` where tuple Item1 is full path and item 2 is filename. Or, just save the full path into one list and rely in [`Path.GetFilename()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the filename.

Comment: Why not using a Tuple or a custom class?

Comment: Simple: What you're doing is a bad idea. Either make a single list of *objects* which have Name and FullPath properties, or keep a single list of full paths and extract the names with Path.GetFileName(path) as needed. Don't do this at all: Solved.

Comment: why are you using two lists to begin with? you can simply just do `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);` or `Path.GetFileName(path); ` on items of your list to get the name of the file.

Comment: Use `List<Dictionary<string,string>>` instead of two lists

Comment: If you cant do what Quantic or vikas mention, I would use linq to combine the two.

Comment: Oh wow I can't believe I didn't even think of Path.GetFileName.

Comment: we all have our blonde moments ;) lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comments above, use a single list of full paths and use the System.Io.Path.FileName method to order by file name regardless of directory.

```
        var list2 = new List<string>() { @"C:\Directory1\B.txt", @"C:\Directory2\A.txt" };
        var orderedList = list2.OrderBy(System.IO.Path.GetFileName);
        //orderedList[0] is @"C:\Directory2\A.txt"
        //orderedList[1] is @"C:\Directory1\B.txt"
```

Comment: That is now what I am doing, This just completely blew over my head and I can't believe it.... I've been so stressed out over this massive system I've made that it caused me to forget one of the most basic things. I will mark as correct as soon as it allows me. Thanks so much guys!

Answer (score 0):

Create a sorted dictionary by zipping the two lists.

```
var sortedDict = new SortedDictionary<string, string>(
        list1.Zip(ist2, (k, v) => new { k, v }).ToDictionary(x => x.k, x => x.v));
```